# Crash Custom EditText in galaxy note 3 (not always, sometimes)

Tags: android, android-edittext

## My Crash Content.

#### 1. `new MyCustomEditText`

```
public class KeyboardManager
{
     private KeybaordEditText editText = null;

     public void Show()
     {
          editText  = new KeybaordEditText(); // crash somtimes 
     }
```

}

### 2. MyCustomEditText Constructor

```
public class KeyboardEditText extends EditText
{
     public KeyboardEditText ()
     {
        super( UnityPlayer.currentActivity ); // <-- crash Somtimes
     }
}
```

### 3. Crash log in Galaxy Note 3 ( Not Always Crash, Intermittenr Crash )

```
    03-11 15:00:44.919: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3054)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3036)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:868)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:79)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:75)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:71)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.ndoors.androidkeyboard.KeyboardEditText.<init>(KeyboardEditText.java:34)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.ndoors.androidkeyboard.KeyboardManager.AddEditText(KeyboardManager.java:232)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.ndoors.androidkeyboard.KeyboardManager.CreateKeyboardView(KeyboardManager.java:217)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.ndoors.androidkeyboard.KeyboardManager.access$1(KeyboardManager.java:194)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.ndoors.androidkeyboard.KeyboardManager$1.run(KeyboardManager.java:70)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-11 15:00:44.929: I/dalvikvm(31770): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is happen?

Comment: Lets see a little more code for this edit text object

Comment: What is this`UnityPlayer.currentActivity` that you're passing in as context to your custom EditText?

Comment: Give us the beginning of the stack trace and the UnityPlayer class pls

Comment: UnityPlayer.currentActivity  is Unity Main Activity.  Unity Main Activity is provided by unity engine

Comment: Why are you calling  `super(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);` in KeyboardEdittext constructor ?

Comment: instead of context. acitivity is inherit the context.